# SaveAs2 method still prompts! Why?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

Context:

> Vb.net program
>   Visual studio 2010 ultimate
>   MS Word 2010 automation
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library

I'm using the saveAs2 method to save a new document I'm creating but the application is still prompting me when I call the method. Why?

The application is not visible.
The application.displayAlerts is false

Any ideas guys?

Also, when I do complete the SaveUI prompt by hand, the saveAs2 method throws an exception.

Here's my code for people who asked for it :

```
    Public Sub generateModel() Implements ModelGenerator.generateModel

    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone

    wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add

    wordDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    wordDoc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    wordDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    wordDoc.PageSetup.RightMargin = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)

    With wordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(wordDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range)

        .Range.Text = _text 
        .Format.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .Format.LineUnitBefore = 1
        .Range.Font.SmallCaps = True
        .Range.Font.Size = 12

    End With

    Dim logo = wordDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(logoLoc)
    logo.Height = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    logo.Width = wordApp.InchesToPoints(1.18)

    Me.mainTable = wordDoc.Tables.Add(wordDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 3, 2)
    mainTable.Rows.HeightRule = Word.WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly
    mainTable.Columns.Width = wordApp.InchesToPoints(4)
    mainTable.Rows.Height = wordApp.InchesToPoints(3.25)
    mainTable.Select()
    wordApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft

    With wordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(wordDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range)

        .Range.Text = "Rapport journalier de production - page 2"
        .Range.Font.Size = 10
        .Format.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .Format.LineUnitBefore = 0
        .Format.SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .Format.SpaceBefore = 0

    End With

    wordDoc.SaveAs2("C:\Doc1.docx")

    wordDoc.Close(False)
    wordApp.Application.Quit()

End Sub
```

**Update:

I tested the code on an other machine and it works. So I tried this code on mine:

```
Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim doc = app.Documents.Add
doc.SaveAs2("C:\Users\simon\Documents\Doc3.docx")
```

And it still makes the saveUI pop up. I'm so confused...

Comment: Why don't you show your code around the SaveAs2 call?

Comment: Here you go I just added the code.

Comment: Which type of exception is thrown? Could you post that as well? Further, you say that: "The application is not visible" -> however, you have `wordApp.Visible = True`, indicating that it should be visible?

Comment: The exception that's thrown is a regular `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` that says "The command failed". And yes in the code snippet I gave you the Application is visible, but I tried it even when it wasn't. Plus it shouldn't matter if the App is visible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the problem's source.

My Acer computer was installing an Add-in everytime I installed Word. Once I removed the Add-in from Word everything went back to normal.

The Add-in was the AcerCloud Add-in.

Comment: In my case it was abDocs Word Addin by Acer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to create a sample implementation in C#, Word Interop API v.15 (Office 2013):

```
var wordApplication = new Application() { Visible = true };
var doc = wordApplication.Documents.Add();
doc.SaveAs2(@"C:\my.docx");
```

... and when you save to a location that requires admin permission (like on the root of the `C:\` drive), Word Interop throws a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` saying that: *"Word cannot save or create this file. Make sure that the disk you want to save the file on is not full, write-protected, or damaged."*

Instead, you should save at a location where your application has the necessary write permissions, e.g., to your own user directory - then it should work as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said that this was not the only path I tried. And the problem is definitely not the exception that is thrown, it's the saveUI that keeps popping up for no reason when I call the method.
What's the "@" you put before the path?

Comment: '@' is used as prefix for a verbatim string in C#. What about the 'SaveAs' method, have you tried that one?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I'm pretty sure the problem is in my installation of ms word